# which algorithm/data structure for file search is used by Sublime Text

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, sublimetext2

Can you give some ideas on how file search feature of Sublime Text is implemented in terms of any special algorithm/data structure they are using.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: everything in this answer is a speculation that probably has nothing in common with reality.

Sublime Text is closed source so nobody can tell you what exact algorithm is used. I can guess that it uses simple regexp search when you search sub-string with `Ctrl+F` and uses some kind of inverted index for tokens (like class or variable names).

It is possible that sublime text uses [gap buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) for text storage, but this data-structure doesn't suits for fast searches.